# Can I more easily format long captions for tables and figures in Jupyter Notebooks rendered to PDF with Quarto?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, quarto

I use Jupyter Notebooks for data analysis, and I would like to use Quarto to couple the research paper PDF to the data analysis.
My discipline (economics and finance) uses *long* figure captions and table captions so figures and tables are fully described and stand alone.
I use a comment like the following to generate a table caption:

```
#| tbl-cap: Counts for All Trades Data with Non-Missing `TRADE_VAR` by Asset and Transaction Types.
```

This comment works well for short captions.
However, it requires left-right scrolling in the code cell to see all the text for 200-word captions.
I have tried and failed to get line breaks with `|` characters.
I want the linebreak in my *code*, not in the *output*.
I want to wrap the markdown code to improve readability in the notebook.
***Can I more easily format long captions for tables and figures in Jupyter Notebooks rendered to PDF with Quarto?***
For example, can I store captions in a variable defined elsewhere in the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if you know you will only being exporting to PDF via LaTeX. You need to use LaTeX \newline to trigger a manual break, but need to escape the first slash as I've done here. Also make sure to put your caption within quotations.

```
#| fig-cap: "Counts for All Trades Data with Non-Missing `TRADE_VAR` by Asset \\newline and Transaction Types."
```

or

```
#| tbl-cap: "Counts for All Trades Data with Non-Missing `TRADE_VAR` by Asset \\newline and Transaction Types."
```

**EDIT 10/17/2023: In Response to Clarification from OP**

You can make multi-line options for the caption of the code chunk like this:

```
#| fig-cap:
#|   - "Counts for All Trades Data with Non-Missing `TRADE_VAR`
#|   by Asset and Transaction Types."
```

Still resulting in correct caption formatting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was not clear. I want the linebreak in my *code*, not in the *output*. I want to wrap the markdown code to improve readability in the notebook.

Comment: @RichardHerron I've edited my answer to include what I believe in your goal, to continue that chunk option on to the next line for code readability. Let me know if that looks about right!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Do you have a reference on how or why your solution works?

Comment: Honestly, I just tried some experimentation based on intuition. I took a look around and couldn't find any other questions on this matter (though I didn't look too long). I know sometimes solutions like these can find themselves buried in the [github](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli) issues.